# How is linear interpolation of data sets usually implemented?

Tags: javascript, math, interpolation

Suppose if you are given a bunch of points in (x,y) values and you need to generate points by linearly interpolate between the 2 nearest values in the x axis, what is the fastest implementation to do so?

I searched around but I was unable to find a satisfactory answer, I feel its because I wasnt searching for the right words.

For example, if I was given (0,0) (0.5 , 1) (1, 0.5), then I want to get a value at 0.7; it would be (0.7-0.5)/(1-0.5) * (0.5-1) + 1; but what data structure would allow me to find the 2 nearest key values to interpolate in between? Is a simple linear search/ binary search if I have many key values the best I could do?

Comment: I guess you will have to do with a sorted associative array.

Comment: I agree associative arrays would be very fast. They have have `O(1)` search complexity.

Comment: @PM77-1: What exactly do you mean? There are no associative arrays in JS. And what keys would you store in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I usually implement O(1) interpolation is by means of an additional data structure, which I call `IntervalSelector` that in time O(1) will give the two surrounding values of the sequence that have to be interpolated.

An `IntervalSelector` is a class that, when given a `sequence` of `n` abscissas builds and remembers a `table` that will map any given value of `x` to the index `i` such that `sequence[i] <= x < sequence[i+1]` in time O(1).

**Note:** In what follows arrays are 1 based.

The algorithm that builds the table proceeds as follow:

1. Find `delta` to be the minimum distance between two consecutive elements in the input `sequence` of abscissas.
2. Set `count := (b-a)/delta + 1`, where `a` and `b` are respectively the first and last of the (ascending) `sequence` and `/` stands for the integer quotient of the division.
3. Define `table` to be an `Array` of `count` elements.
4. For `i` between `1` and `n` set `table[(sequence[j]-a)/delta + 1] := j.`
5. Repeat every entry of `table` visited in 4 to the unvisited positions that come right after it.

On output, `table` maps `j` to `i` if `(j-1)*d <= sequence[i] - a < j*d.`

Here is an example:

[image]

Since elements 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> are the closest ones, we divide the interval in subintervals of this smallest length. Now, we remember in the `table` the positions of the left end of each of these `deta-`intervals. Later on, when an input `x` is given, we compute the `delta-`interval of such `x` as `(x-a)/delta + 1` and use the table to deduce the corresponding interval in the sequence. If `x` falls to the left of the `i`th sequence element, we choose the `(i-1)`th.

More precisely:

Given any input `x` between `a` and `b` calculate `j := (x-a)/delta + 1` and `i := table[j].` If `x < sequence[i]` put `i := i - 1`. Then, the index `i` satisfies `sequence[i] <= x < sequence[i+1]`; otherwise the distance between these two consecutive elements would be smaller than `delta`, which is not.

**Remark:** Be aware that if the minimum distance `delta` between consecutive elements in `sequence` is too small the table will have too many entries. The simple description I've presented here ignores these pathological cases, which require additional work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a simple binary search should do well and will typically suffice.

If you need to get better, you might try [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) (has nothing to do with your value interpolation).

If your points are distributed at fixed intervals (like in your example, `0 0.5 1`), you can also simply store the values in an array and access them in constant time via their index.