# C# Data Structure for a set of (x,y) points

Tags: c#, math, collections, relation

I'm not familiar with all the collections available in C# but I'd like to implement a class to store a mathematical relation or function, i.e. a set of pairs (x,y).  Presumably it would include a list of tuples or some other built collection from .NET, but I'm not sure what's best.  Some potentially relevant facts:

1. up a million pairs
2. frequently would want to lookup which y goes with a particular x
3. x would be a double type for all cases I know of now
4. may want to interpolate y's to nonexistant x's
5. will want to extract a subset of the relation including all pairs with x in a certain range
6. will want to iterate through pairs in order of xs sometimes
   seems like it should be sorted by xs based on above things?

Comment: Is it going to be sorted or not? Are you going to need to access a lot of the items or just a few at a time? Why do you need a double precision do you really need such a accurate answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995766/comparison-of-collection-datatypes-in-c-sharp

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking. Do you need a class that stores some tuples of x,y values? (Then use a dictionary/List/any other collection that you see fit) Or are you looking for a way to represent a given function and have trouble implementing that function in c# (in which case storing tuples is a bad idea, but you are looking to create a method that returns the y-value for a given x)?

Comment: For other ideas for interpolating data sets (with javascript as language) see this detailed answer, essentially implementing a binning or boxing strategy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29224011/3088138

Comment: Regarding questions above, don't explicitly need it stored sorted, but based on the stated usage I was guessing it probably should be for efficiency?  Would the answer be different for different floating point types?  I said double but may use float or other.

Answer (score 4):

The [`SortedSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) seems like the right tool for this task.

We can define an `IComparable` element type as follows.

```
struct FunctionPoint : IComparable<FunctionPoint>
{
    public double X, Y;
    public FunctionPoint(double x)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = 0;
    }
    public FunctionPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
    public int CompareTo(FunctionPoint other)
    {
        return X.CompareTo(other.X);
    }
}
```

And then use it in a `SortedSet<FunctionPoint>` as follows.

```
var function = new SortedSet<FunctionPoint>();
```

> 1. up a million pairs

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var x = 2 * Math.PI * i / 1000000;
    var y = Math.Sin(x);
    function.Add(new FunctionPoint { X = x, Y = y });
}
```

> 2. frequently would want to lookup which y goes with a particular x

```
var view = function.GetViewBetween(new FunctionPoint(x), new FunctionPoint(x));
if (view.Count > 0)
{
    var y = view.Min;
}
```

> 4. may want to interpolate y's to nonexistant x's

```
var left = function.GetViewBetween(new FunctionPoint(double.NegativeInfinity), new FunctionPoint(x)).Max;
var right = function.GetViewBetween(new FunctionPoint(x), new FunctionPoint(double.PositiveInfinity)).Min;
var y = LinearInterpolate(left, right, x);
```

> 5. will want to extract a subset of the relation including all pairs with x in a certain range

```
var view = function.GetViewBetween(new FunctionPoint(a), new FunctionPoint(b));
```

> 6. will want to iterate through pairs in order of xs sometimes seems like it should be sorted by xs based on above things?

```
foreach (var point in function)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this addresses the things I need for now as long as the efficiency is reasonable.

Comment: @Mat My understanding is that internally the `SortedSet<T>` is using a red-black tree, which is going to be fairly efficient for this sort of thing.  If you aren't doing insertions and removals frequently (or at all) a `SortedList<T>` might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<double, double>` is what you need?
[SortedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you constantly remove and add items, a [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might perform better.